# How to run sonar-runner with module's baseDir set to root project dir

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have the following project structure:

- module1
- module2

  - module2.1
  - module2.2
  - module2.3

And have sonar-project.properties defined as:

```
sonar.projectKey=example
sonar.projectName=project
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.language=xml
sonar.sources=.
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.forceAnalysis=true
sonar.projectBaseDir=.

sonar.modules=module2, module1, xml

xml.sonar.projectBaseDir=/

module1.sonar.language=js
module1.sonar.exclusions=lib/**

module2.sonar.language=java
module2.sonar.modules=module2.1,module2.2,module2.3

module2.1.sonar.sources=/src/main/java/
module2.1.sonar.binaries=/target/classes

module2.2.sonar.sources=/src/main/java/
module2.2.sonar.binaries=/target/classes

module2.3.sonar.sources=/src/main/java/
module2.3.sonar.binaries=/target/classes
```

I want to analyse module1 using js profile, module2.1,2.2,2.3 using java profile, and all of the xml files, which could be in the project. The current solution gives me `Java heap space` because `xml.sonar.projectBaseDir` is set to `/` (tried also with `.` and `../root`, for all these result is the same).

Could, please, somebody help me and tell how to analyse all the project dirs using xml profile.

Thanks in advance!

p.s. creating two more modules to analyse module1 and module2 folders doesn't fit me, because I have .xml files in the root folder as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the upcoming version 2.1 of the Sonar Runner, this issue will be solved: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARUNNER-43

Comment: Thank you, Fabrice! Can we expect new release of sonar runner in nearest future or it's unknown for now when it will be released?

Comment: Sonar Runnner 2.1 is expected to be released before end of March 2013.